# some syntax issues im facing with python

Tags: python

Hey so i have started with python recently and im facing a syntax error when im trying to activate this code with python 3.1
This code is from the Automate the Boring Stuff and it's exactly the same as the author used and mine is facing an Error, any idea ?
btw the Error is with the elif condition

```
import random

print('Hello. What is your name?')
name = input()

print('Well, ' + name + ', I am thinking of a number between 1 to 20 ')
secretNumber = random.randint(1, 20)

for guessesTaken in range(1, 7):
    print('Take a guess.')
    guess = int(input())

    if guess < secretNumber:
        print('Your guess is too low.')
        elif guess > secretNumber:
            print ('Your guess is too high.')
            else:
                break
if guess == secretNumber:
    print('Good job, ' + name + '! You guessed my number in ' + str(guessesTaken) + ' guesses')
    else:
        print(' Nope, that number i was thinking of was ' + str(secretNumber))
```

Comment: Could you indent your code correctly ? It's not easy to read.

Comment: Python considers indentation significant. Is that `elif` aligned with the `if`? Similarly, you have an `else` later in the code. Is it aligned with `if`?

Comment: Your `elif` indentation is off (too nested), same for `else`.

Comment: hey thanks for answering everybody. could someone fix this code so i can see what my mistake was? i understand what youre all trying to say but i cant figure it out tbh lol tried so many times, Thanks !

Comment: Sure, see below

Comment: Python 3.1 was released on 2009-06-27 and is EOL since 2012-04-09. Are you sure that's what you are using?

Comment: The `.` is a separator, not a decimal point. It maybe be you're using "3.10" vs. "3.1".

Answer (score 2):

code with identation fixed which ran on my machine

```
import random

print('Hello. What is your name?')
name = input()

print('Well, ' + name + ', I am thinking of a number between 1 to 20 ')
secretNumber = random.randint(1, 20)

for guessesTaken in range(1, 7):
    print('Take a guess.')
    guess = int(input())

    if guess < secretNumber:
        print('Your guess is too low.')
    elif guess > secretNumber:
        print ('Your guess is too high.')
    else:
        break

if guess == secretNumber:
    print('Good job, ' + name + '! You guessed my number in ' + str(guessesTaken) + ' guesses')
else:
    print(' Nope, that number i was thinking of was ' + str(secretNumber))
```

Comment: oh thanks lol seems kinda same but i understood what the problem was, thanks !

Comment: @YeheliVivo yeah it is highly similar but indentation is very important in python as it is used for flow control. This is not very common in other programming languages. As rule a rule of thumb anything you want to run inside anything will be one indent in

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct indentation:

```
import random

print('Hello. What is your name?')
name = input()

print('Well, ' + name + ', I am thinking of a number between 1 to 20 ')
secretNumber = random.randint(1, 20)

for guessesTaken in range(1, 7):
    print('Take a guess.')
    guess = int(input())

    if guess < secretNumber:
        print('Your guess is too low.')
    elif guess > secretNumber:
        print ('Your guess is too high.')
    else:
        break
if guess == secretNumber:
    print('Good job, ' + name + '! You guessed my number in ' + str(guessesTaken) + ' guesses')
else:
    print(' Nope, that number i was thinking of was ' + str(secretNumber))
```

Answer (score 0):

Indentation is a very important concept of Python!
You have indentation errors on your code, elif and else should be indented at the same level of if. Same for the second 'else'.

```
import random

print('Hello. What is your name?')
name = input()

print('Well, ' + name + ', I am thinking of a number between 1 to 20 ')
secretNumber = random.randint(1, 20)

for guessesTaken in range(1, 7):
    print('Take a guess.')
    guess = int(input())

    if guess < secretNumber:
        print('Your guess is too low.')
    elif guess > secretNumber:
        print ('Your guess is too high.')
    else:
        break
if guess == secretNumber:
    print('Good job, ' + name + '! You guessed my number in ' + str(guessesTaken) + ' guesses')
else:
    print(' Nope, that number i was thinking of was ' + str(secretNumber))
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer:
I'm a bit of a newb myself so there could be better answers out there.

Python is all about indentation. The indentations of the if/elif/else should be all on the same level. See below:

```
if guess < secretNumber:
    print('Your guess is too low.')
elif guess > secretNumber:
    print ('Your guess is too high.')
else:
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this. Note the indentation of the if/else statements.

```py
import random

print('Hello. What is your name?')
name = input()

print('Well, ' + name + ', I am thinking of a number between 1 to 20 ')
secretNumber = random.randint(1, 20)

for guessesTaken in range(1, 7):
    print('Take a guess.')
    guess = int(input())

    if guess < secretNumber:
        print('Your guess is too low.')
    elif guess > secretNumber:
        print ('Your guess is too high.')
    else:
        break

if guess == secretNumber:
    print('Good job, ' + name + '! You guessed my number in ' + str(guessesTaken) 
    +' guesses')
else:
    print(' Nope, that number i was thinking of was ' + str(secretNumber))
```